# ¿Por qué no funciona este algoritmo de burbuja? C++

Tags: c++

Me toquetea el vector de strings un poco pero no hace lo que tiene que hacer, cambia 2 o 3 palabras y ya está

```
void intercambia (string& a, string& b)
{
    string aux;
    aux=a;
    a=b;
    b=aux;
return;
```

}

```
void Burbuja(string vfich[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=(n-1); j>=i; j--)
        {
            if (vfich[j].length()>vfich[j-1].length()) intercambia (vfich[j], vfich[j-1]);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de qué lista de strings le pasas y que lista de strings obtienes?

Comment: Es un archivo de texto de 22000 lineas, te pongo las primeras lineas;

Comment: Me devuelve: 
EXTRATERRITORIALIDAD
A
ABACO
ABAD
ABADEJO
ABADESA
ABADIA
ABAJE¥O
ABAJO
ABALORIO
ABANDONADO
ABANDONAR
ABANDONO
ABANICO
ABARATAR
ABARCA
ABARRAGANAMIENTO
ABARROTADO
ABARROTAR
ABARROTE
ABASTECEDOR
ABASTECER
ABASTECIMIENTO

Comment: Le introduzco; A
ABACO
ABAD
ABADEJO
ABADESA
ABADIA
ABAJE¥O
ABAJO
ABALORIO
ABANDONADO
ABANDONAR
ABANDONO
ABANICO
ABARATAR
ABARCA
ABARRAGANAMIENTO
ABARROTADO
ABARROTAR
ABARROTE
ABASTECEDOR
ABASTECER
ABASTECIMIENTO

Answer (score 3):

Pues veo al menos tres errores:

**1.-el `return` antes de tiempo.** Tu return esta dentro de tu primer `for`, lo que ocaciona que `i` solo se incremente una sola vez.

**2.- `j` no se inicia correctamente**: Tienes `j=(n-1);` la cual debes de cambia o al menos hacer `n--` en algun momento.

**3.- tu condicion `if`**: Se que todos tenemos diferentes formas de solucionar problemas pero en lo personal `if (vfich[j].length()>vfich[j-1].length())` creo que jamas funcionaria

Entonces te dejo un ejemplo que podria funcionarte

```
void Burbuja(string vfich[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (vfich[j].length()>vfich[i].length()) intercambia (vfich[j], vfich[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

No tengo C++, instalado razon por la cual no puedo probarlo, pero estoy seguro que funcionaria.

Answer (score -2):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
void Burbuja(string vfich[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n-1; j++)
        {
            if (vfich[j].length()>vfich[j+1].length()) intercambia (vfich[j], vfich[j+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: se te agradece el apoyo, pero no es solo poner código y ya; debes explicarlo; de lo contrario se considera de baja calidad